# Question about the spiral formation

Tags: structure-formation

Im new to physics and i have been wondering about the spiral formation that can be seen occuring in Nature, e.g. Spiral galaxies, DNA strains, Bacteria strains, some flowers have the spiral form, also some sea shells have it.

- How do this spiral structure occur?
- Does it occur because its the most energy-efficent or the strongest structure?

Thank you for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spiral effect occurs In galaxies is because of gravitational density waves clumping the material together.

I am referring here only to the physics part of your question and the reasons spiral shaped biological shells etc. occur is not related to gravity, you would have to post that as a separate question on Biology SE.

If you Google "Fibonacci Series" you will find out more about spiral structures in biology.

Does it occur because it is is the strongest structure? Not with galaxies, but it could be part of biological structures.

In the sense of energy-efficient, all natural systems and structures, from atoms to galaxies,  will form to minimise their overall potential energy.

An interesting point is that it was shown, 40 years ago, that without a dark matter halo, the spiral arms, over the long term, would disappear.

This was one of the early indications of the possible existence of dark matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a comprehensive answer in lay mans terms since im not well familiar with the math yet. I appreciate the advice about the biology-aspect of the question.

Comment: Your welcome, just to explain a bit more, dark matter is important because it's a large part of the matter of the universe, there is much more of it than stuff like galaxies and stars that we can easily see. It pulls on things gravitationally,  but does not show up any other way. So we can't see it and we need to find out what it is. Best of luck with the biology part, here's a link to how the spiral pattern in nature is related to the math in the Fibonicci series http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emat6680/parveen/fib_nature.htm

Comment: Cool, thank you. About the dark matter. Is it because its on another wave length or frequency that we cannot see it or why does it not interact with other matter? Im very exited that CERN got the LHC up and running on 13 TEV beams now. Do you think they will cast some "light" onto the dark matter?

Comment: Thats a really interesting link you just gave me! Please see the structure of these snowflakes: http://www.boredpanda.com/snowflake-macro-photography-diy-alexey-kljatov/. Incredible huh. Where do the blueprints for these structures come from?

Comment: Another terrible pun like that, no more comments:) all the matter we know about, from atoms, through us, up to stars, normally interacts with two or more forces, so we can see the Moon, reflecting electromagnetic radiation and we can also "feel" it's gravitational pull in the tides. With dark matter, we guess it's the thing that is pulling on the galaxies, but we don't have any other easy way to study it.

Comment: Snowflakes, this link might help, http://www.noaa.gov/features/02_monitoring/snowflakes_2013.html     They will also be governed by trying to minimise potential energy....gotta go...good luck with it

Comment: Thanks for the advice and links Jazz :) I appreciate it.

Comment: no prob, happy to help.